# position work well in firefox and not working in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a drop down menu in my header, and I want when a button that is in my header clicked the drop-down menu shows bellow that button.

that button position is absolute and I use jquery position to get that button left and bottom. But that is just working in firefox. Why?

This is my code:

```
var search_div_top=($("#search-div").position().top);
var search_div_left=($("#search-div").position().left);
```

and this is my css:

```
#search-div{
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
   /*center:*/
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

just firefox return real number of left and right of that element, and others return 0. The parent of `#search-div` is `relative`.

Comment: can you create a demo jsfiddle.com or a snippet

Comment: @0_o unfortiently I can't, I created one but worked in chrome and firefox both ok! I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the problem?**

The Chrome and other browsers (not Firefox) problem is:

```
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
```

with above CSS the div will shows in center of its parent, and if you see in above code we have `left:0` and `right:0` and chrome see this code and get one of this and start from left or right with 0 value.

**so, What is the solution:**

in jquery there is a function to getting position of an element, just use bellow code:

```
var search_div_top=($("#search-div").offset().top);
var search_div_left=($("#search-div").offset().left);
```